# What is the greedy approach for this?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, greedy

We have an array of `n` numbers which all of them except one have been repeated an even amount of times in this array; we want to find the number that is repeated an odd number of times.

I think the optimum algorithm has time complexity better than `O( n Log(n) )` because we can sort the array and then iterate it and when ever we see a new number we increase an accumulator and when we see it again we decrease the accumulator and at the end each member whose accumulator is not zero have been repeated odd times.

Also I think it does not have an algorithm better than `O(n)` because if it has then it must be `O( Log(n) )` and for that we need a sorted array but our initial array is not.

Comment: Are the numbers integers? (It's important.)

Comment: You can solve this in `O(n)` if you're okay with consuming `O(n)` space: create a dictionary that maps number values with a count.

Comment: BTW, your reasoning that the algorithm can't be better than `O(n)` is flawed (though the conclusion is correct).

Comment: Also, please clarify if "repeated" means they appear in sequential runs in the array, or if you just want to count appearances in the array regardless of their neighbours.

Comment: @Dai the use of hashtables (aka dictionaries) leads to an `O(n)` best/average case, but an `O(n^2)` worst case.

Comment: @Sneftel to clarify, you're referring to space complexity, not time?

Comment: @Dai no, time complexity. (Space is still `O(n)`.) If the numbers in the array happen to all hash to the same value, hash table insertion becomes Schlemiel The Painter's algorithm.

Comment: @Sneftel ordinarily, but assuming these are 4-byte numbers (`Int32`, `Single`, etc) then the raw number value can be used as the key directly without needing to compute the hash or worry about collisions.

Comment: @Dai I don't see that stipulation in the problem. Also, not sure he  wants an `O(2^k)` algorithm.

Comment: @Dai the repeated numbers are not continues and may appear every where in array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the numbers are integers you can just xor all the values in your array. The result is the number that is repeated odd number of times(it is correct because `x xor x = 0` for any `x`). The complexity of this algorithm is obviously `O(n)`.

Comment: take care our numbers are not integer.they're real number but I can't understand why we can't xor Real numbers?

Comment: @amirveyseh If we want to compare floating-point numbers without error tolerance, then yes, we can cast them to integers and xor them.

Comment: @amirveyseh Bitwise-XOR is well-defined over fixed-precision floats. It is technically defined over real numbers as well, but such an operation is not generally considered to be an `O(1)` one within the context of complexity theory.

Comment: so i think if i iterate the original array and find the most number of floating digits and then multiply all members by this then i can use integer xor? i mean for example in (2.3,2,3.34,4.023) we convert it to (2300,2000,3340,4023)

Comment: @amirveyseh You can just interpter the in-memory representation of a float number as an integer.